# Which join should i use for getting record from 4 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have four tables which is like this

```
---user table---|--Form table-----|---Request status-- |--Request Table--
UserId Username |FormId FormTitle |RequestId  StatusId |RequestId Title UserId FormId
1      Test     |   1      Form1  |    1     1         |   1       Request1  1  1
2      User     |   2      Form2  |    2     1         |   2       Request2  1  1
```

I want to pull the record from table like this

```
RequestId  FormTitle UserName Status
    1        Test       1      1
```

But currently I am getting multiple record for below query

```
select r.RequestId,f.FormTitle,u.UserId, rs.StatusId from request r 
 Join requeststatus rs on rs.StatusId=rs.StatusId
 left join [user] u on u.UserId=u.UserId
 left join form f on f.FormId=f.FormId
where r.RequestId=1
```

Which join should I user to achieve this?

Comment: you have a typo in your statement "rs.StatusId=rs.StatusId" - should be r.StatisId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a little typo in your JOIN-condition.
Try to format your statements. It will be easier to support and analyze them later.

In your case, try:

```
           SELECT r.RequestId
                 ,f.FormTitle
                 ,u.UserId
                 ,rs.StatusId
             FROM request r 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN requeststatus rs 
               ON rs.RequestId  = r.RequestId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user u 
               ON u.UserId      = r.UserId             
  LEFT OUTER JOIN form f 
               ON f.FormId      = r.FormId         
            WHERE r.RequestId   = 1
```

Your `JOINS` won't work if you do like:

```
u.UserId=u.UserId
```

As you are joining columns from the same table "`u`"

Comment: But my `request table` doesn't contain `StatusId` column ??

Comment: @Lifewithsun sorry, i updated my answer. changed StatusId to RequestId

Answer (score 3):

This is pointless:

```
 Join requeststatus rs on rs.StatusId = rs.StatusId
```

you want

```
Join requeststatus rs on r.RequestId = rs.RequestId
```

The same with the other joins

So this should work:

```
select r.RequestId,f.FormTitle,u.UserId, rs.StatusId 
from request r 
left join  requeststatus rs on r.RequestId = rs.RequestId 
left join [user] u on r.UserId = u.UserId
left join form f on r.FormId = f.FormId
where r.RequestId = 1
```

Comment: But my `request `table doesn't contain `StatusId` column ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this query.  I think your issue is you're not really joining one table to another.  You're joining same table to itself:

```
SELECT r.RequestId
,f.FormTitle
,u.UserId
,rs.StatusId
FROM request r
JOIN requeststatus rs ON rs.RequestID = r.RequestID
LEFT JOIN [user] u ON u.UserId = r.UserId
LEFT JOIN form f ON f.FormId = r.FormId
WHERE r.RequestId = 1
```

Comment: From my observation, I believe you're a beginner in SQL.  One suggestion:  instead of using aliases try using entire table name.  Example:  JOIN RequestStatus ON RequestStatus.RequestID  = Request.RequestID.  This will help clearly see which tables you're joining on.  Another thing you can do is define aliases better.  Example:  Request table alias can be called "Req"  and RequestStatus table alias can be called "ReqSt".

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why everyone is using left joins.  Inner join works as well, and IMHO is much to be preferred where possible.  So:

```
SELECT r.RequestId, f.FormTitle, u.UserId, rs.StatusId
    FROM request r 
INNER JOIN requeststatus rs 
    ON rs.requestid = r.requestid
INNER JOIN [user] u 
    ON u.UserId = r.UserId             
INNER JOIN form f 
    ON f.FormId = r.FormId         
WHERE r.RequestId = 1
```

Comment: Not everyone is using left joins but op did and since using inner join doesn't fix this issue it's just confusing to use them. Maybe op has another reason to use left joins

Comment: @TimSchmelter But OP got so much else wrong, so why not suggest inner as well?  And the select does work with inner join!